# Was bedeutet "für die Füße sein"?

Tags: meaning, phrase

> Heute war die Vorlesung aber komplett für die Füße.

Im Buch habe ich diese Phrase gefunden. Was bedeutet das? Ist sie alt?

Comment: Es gibt eine Reihe von Redensarten mit *Fuß*, aber keines das diesem ähnelt. Ich würde in dem Kontext eher von *für die Katz* sprechen. Wahrscheinlich fand der Autor im Kontext es angemessen, die Redensart durch den Wolf zu drehen. Anders kann ich mir das nicht erklären.

Comment: Um welches Buch handelt es sich denn?

Comment: In der Schweiz kennt man einen ähnlichen Ausdruck: "Das isch für d'Füchs" (Das ist für die Füchse) und hat auch die Bedeutung von "vergebens sein".

Comment: @Em1 naja, die Redensart "für die Füße sein" ist schon häufiger als du denkst! Kann man aber natürlich auch der Umgangssprache zuordnen.

Comment: @klyonrad Eher regional. Ich hatte diese "Redensart" nämlich inzw. wieder gänzlich vergessen, weil - wie zu erwarten - seitdem auch keinmal gehört.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm - spontan denke ich eher an eine "entschärfte" Variante von ["für den A... sein"](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~fuer%20den%20Arsch%20sein&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou). Der Einsatz eines anderen "Körperteils" entschärft nicht nur, sondern erzeugt auch einen leicht komisch-sarkastischen Effekt (die Redensart zieht ja gerade ihre Wirksamkeit aus der außerordentlich derben Wortwahl - und gerade das derbe "Ankerwort" wird ausgetauscht).

Zum **Alter** kann ich nichts sagen - jedenfalls nicht sonderlich alt, maximal 10 bis 15 Jahre?

Zur **Bedeutung**: was "für den A..." oder eben "für die Füße" ist, ist völlig unbrauchbar, nutzlos; die dafür aufgewandte Zeit ist komplett vergeudet; und wer die Formulierung verwendet, ist darüber sehr, sehr verärgert.

Wenn die Vorlesung "für die Füße" war, war sie also verlorene Zeit - man hat dort nichts gelernt und auch nicht irgendwelche netten Leute getroffen oder anderen Nebennutzen ziehen können - man wäre besser gleich daheim geblieben.

Noch ein Hinweis: Die verlinkten Varianten sind teils ziemlich derb und grob - man sollte sie nicht in jeder Situation verwenden!

Answer (score 6):

> Das ist doch für die Füße.

ist zumindest im Rhein-Ruhr-Gebiet ein völlig normaler Ausdruck für

> Das ist vergebens.

Wie alt er ist kann ich nicht sagen, aber mittelalterlich ist er sicherlich nicht.

Aus naheliegenden Gründen ist es nahezu unmöglich den Ausdruck im Internet zu recherchieren, da nun mal vieles tatsächlich "für die Füße" ist, im wörtlichen Sinne von

> Diese Schuhe sind besonders gut für die Füße.

etc.

Man findet den Ausdruck trotzdem auch im Netz in der eingangs von mir genannten Bedeutung, dann aber meist in umgangssprachlichen Kommentaren und Forumsbeiträgen.

Answer (score 2):

Es bedeutet "eine nutz- und sinnlose Angelegenheit zu bezeichnen". 
Ich habe also auch [diesen lustigen Artikel](http://derstandard.at/2916059/Fuer-die-Fuesse) gefunden:

> Für die Füße
>
> Redaktion, 19. Juni 2007, 15:45
>
> Eine sinnlose Angelegenheit
>
> Meine geschätzte Kollegin K. hat mir geschrieben, dass bei den
>   Deutschen die Formulierung „das ist für die Füße“ im Schwang sei, um
>   eine nutz- und sinnlose Angelegenheit zu bezeichnen. Dazu darf ich
>   anmerken, dass diese Redewendung hierzulande ungebräuchlich ist. Eher
>   würde man wohl sagen, die betreffende Sache sei für den Hugo, für die
>   Wiascht oder, wenn man die untere Schublade nicht scheut, für den
>   Arsch. Ich nehme an, dass die p.t. Leser gewiss noch die eine oder
>   andere hierher passende Wortspende in petto haben.
>
> Zudem muss ich gestehen, dass mir der Füße-Spruch nicht unbedingt
>   sympathisch ist, weil er eine unverdiente Abwertung dieser nützlichen
>   Körperteile transportiert. Die Franzosen sind hier definitiv weniger
>   fußfeindlich als die Deutschen; „“c’est le pied“, wörtlich: „das ist
>   der Fuß!“ bedeutet „das ist hervorragend, ausgezeichnet“, allerdings
>   gibt es auch den Ausdruck „s’y prendre comme un pied“, „sich wie ein
>   Fuß benehmen“, nämlich ungeschickt, tölpelhaft. Im Deutschen existiert
>   eine verschwenderische Vielfalt von Fuß-Redewendungen. Hier seien nur
>   zwei weniger bekannte erwähnt, nämlich „zwei Füße in einem Schuh
>   haben“, was so viel bedeutet wie „schwanger sein“, sowie „sich einen
>   weißen Fuß bei jemandem machen“. Das heißt: sich bei jemandem beliebt
>   machen, einschmeicheln, eine Vorzugstellung verschaffen. Das englische
>   „to give a person the white foot“ hat dieselbe Bedeutung (zit. nach
>   Lutz Röhrich, Das große Lexikon der sprichwörtlichen Redensarten). Für
>   den Fall, dass Ihnen beim Lesen ein paar nette Fuß-Assoziationen
>   aufgestiegen sind, bitte ich darum, sie stante pede der Allgemeinheit
>   mitzuteilen.
>
> Von Christoph Winder
>
> Winders Wörterbuch zur Gegenwart ist ein Work in Progress.
>
> Zweckdienliche Hinweise auf bemerkens- und erörternswerte Wörter sind
>   erbeten an christoph.winder@derStandard.at.

Comment: Wie die vielen "kenn ich nicht"-Beiträge hier zeigen, ist es wohl etwas zu sehr verallgemeinert wenn Herr Winder behauptet der Ausdruck sei bei "den Deutschen" im Schwang.

Comment: Ihm wurde es mitgeteilt, aber ja, da hast du auch sowieso recht. :)

Comment: Du hast recht, die Kollegin K. ist schuld. :)

Answer (score 0):

**für die Füße <-> für die Fische?**
"Für die Füße" habe ich noch nie gehört. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass dieser Ausdruck aus einem Hör-Fehler entstanden ist. Sehr ähnlich klingt nämlich "für die Fische", das zumindest im Osten Österreichs sehr verbreitet ist. Dem steht aber entgegen, dass der Ausdruck angeblich in einem Buch stand. Aber vielleicht hat sich auch der Autor des Buches verhört?

**Für die Fische**
Wenn man in einem Boot auf einem Gewässer herumfährt, wirft man Speisereste und Küchenabfälle einfach über Bord. Dieser biologisch einwandfreie Abfall wird dann gierig von Fischen gefressen. Dieser Abfall ist also *für die Fische*.

Auch wenn jemand seekrank wird und sich den Inhalt seines Magens ein zweites Mal durch den Kopf gehen lässt, gehen die bereits vorverdauten Bestandteile der Nahrung über Bord und landen im Wasser. Also ist auch das Erbrochene *für die Fische*.

Wenn also etwas *für die Fische* ist, ist es zwar ungefährlich und harmlos, aber eben völlig überflüssig und nutzlos.

Comment: Nein, es ist kein Hörfehler und keine Verwechslung. Den Ausdruck gibt es wirklich.

Comment: Aber es ist eine interessante Theorie für die Herkunft: Vielleicht hat ja ein Rheinländer einen Österreicher "für die Fische" sagen hören (entweder, weil der Rheinländer Österreich besucht hat, oder der Österreicher das Rheinland), hat "für die Füße" verstanden, das lustig gefunden und selbst verwendet, und das hat sich dann verbreitet. Das ist jetzt natürlich nur eine reine Spekulation ohne jeglichen konkreten Anhaltspunkt außer der erwähnten Ähnlichkeit der beiden Ausdrücke, aber zumindest nicht völlig unplausibel.

Comment: Um ehrlich zu sein finde ich schon die Behauptung, "für die Füße" klinge ähnlich wie "für die Fische" arg konstruiert. Hochdeutsch gesprochen trifft das jedenfalls nicht zu.

Comment: Da klingt ja der schweizer Begriff erheblich ähnlicher, siehe allotrias Antwort.